# What does this mean in database - ⊆?

Tags: database

What does this symbol in database mean ⊆?

for example for projection in relational algebra :

Π<sub>L</sub>R

take a subset of the attributes of a relation R,
where L ⊆ R.

Comment: L ⊆ R means L is contained in R ('is a subset of')

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L ⊆ R means L is a subset of R.

For every element in L, the element exists in R.

Comment: I knew I should have answered instead of just commenting first.

Answer (score 0):

L ⊆ R means L is a subset of R ('is contained in').

[L could also be equal to the whole of R].

Answer (score 0):

L ⊆ R means L is subset of or equal to R.

Comment: How is this different from the previous answers?

Answer (score 0):

L and R make set of attributes

Answer (score -1):

L ⊆ R means literally L is a subset of R.

In order to understand it here is an example, we have two sets A and B:

```
A = {1, 4, 5}
B = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

where A is a subset of B, because all numbers from set A can be found in set B. Also, we can see it as a diagram:

[image]

Now we can write it using the math notation:

```
A ⊆ B
```

I recommend to have a look on these pages, just to solid your knowledge:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset

https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/symbols.html

Comment: Thanks; a great and very clear answer. The example is awesome and helps tremendously. Question: what happens if **A = {1, 4, 5, 7, 9}**, how does this affect the answer?

Comment: it would be not a subset of B :)